# Looking for the exact list of possible MethodAttributes.SpecialName

Tags: .net, cil, cls-compliant

I am aware of `ctor`, `cctor`, property/indexer prefix: `get_`, `set_`, event management prefix: `add_`, `remove_`.
I have seen a `raise_` prefix once or twice (do not remember where).

Does a definitive list exists at the .Net level (ECMA spec.)? If yes where is it?

Is it an "open list" so that any (new) language can define them for its (future) needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User defined operators would be another example.  Like System.String.op_Equality (operator==):

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static bool op_Equality(string a, string b) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldarg.1 
    L_0002: call bool System.String::Equals(string, string)
    L_0007: ret 
}
```

There's no exhaustive list, language implementations are free to use the attribute to hide their glue.  You probably saw the raise_ prefix on code generated by the VB.NET compiler using the RaiseEvent accessor for example.